# Async updating a dictionary on a database

Tags: python, database, asynchronous

So I'm new to async programming, but probably my problem has something to do with racing conditions.
I'm using Odmantic with MongoDB on this case.

I'm trying to populate a database for testing purposes, so I have this data, for example:

```py
categories = [
    {
        'name': 'Accessories'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Apparel'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Groceries'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Paints',
        'parent': 'Accessories'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Homewares',
        'parent': 'Accessories'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Audiobooks',
        'parent': 'Accessories'
    },
    {
        'name': 'T-shirts',
        'parent': 'Apparel'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Polo Shirts',
        'parent': 'Apparel'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Hoodies',
        'parent': 'Apparel'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Footwear',
        'parent': 'Apparel'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Juices',
        'parent': 'Groceries'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Alcohol',
        'parent': 'Groceries'
    },
]
```

So I start like this:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    if argv[1] == 'populate':
        loop.run_until_complete(populate())
    elif argv[1] == 'clear':
        loop.run_until_complete(clear())
    loop.close()
```

My populate function:

```py
async def populate():
    tasks = []
    print('\nPopulating Categories:')
    for cat in categories:
        task = help_populate_cats(cat)
        tasks.append(task)
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

The two helpers:

```py
async def help_populate_cats(cat):
    category = Category(name=cat.get('name'))
    await category.create()
    await helper_constructor(category)
    print(f"{cat.get('name')} added.")
```

```py
async def helper_constructor(element):
    for field in element.translations:
        if isinstance(getattr(element, field), str) or not getattr(element, field):
            for lang in available_languages:
                db_language = await Language.get_language(lang)
                if lang == 'en-US':
                    temp_translations = {f'{element.id}_{field}': getattr(element, field)}
                else:
                    temp_translations = {f'{element.id}_{field}': None}
                await db_language.add_strings(temp_translations)
```

and finally the class Language:

```py
class Language(Model, ABC):
    prefix: str
    strings: Optional[dict] = {}

    class Config:
        collection = 'languages'

    @classmethod
    async def get_language(cls, prefix: str) -> "Language":
        return await engine.find_one(cls, cls.prefix == prefix)

    async def add_strings(self, strings: dict):
        self.strings.update(**strings)
        # update_strings(self.prefix, self.strings)
        await self.save()

    async def save(self):
        await engine.save(self)
```

After running this code my database looks like this [image: this]:

```
Engine Started

Populating Categories:
Homewares added.
Juices added.
T-shirts added.
Groceries added.
Audiobooks added.
Apparel added.
Paints added.
Polo Shirts added.
Accessories added.
Hoodies added.
Alcohol added.
Footwear added.
```

I have other items like product types and attributes, and it fills like randomly the database (the language part, creating the categories works fine), some things go in others don't, but if I print when on the add_strings method, everything appears there (on the print, not on the database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have switched computers and networks, and it is working fine, I find out randomly, so I guess the code is ok.